# "Undefined variable" error in PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to extract the information on [this page](https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-7475119/) using a script PHP Simple HTML DOM,
Here is part of the code I wrote:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-7475119/');
foreach ($html->find('p.color-900') as $e) {
            $color = $e->outertext;
            echo  $color ;
            break;
        }
```

But unfortunately the output I receive is `Undefined variable`

Comment: You need to be able to run JavaScript in order to create the DOM tree you expect. Otherwise that element doesn't exist.

Comment: @KevinY Please explain a little more

Comment: @MartinZeitler Unfortunately no

Comment: Visit `view-source:https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-7475119/` and search for `<p`. You won't find a single P tag on the page. This is because in your browser it can run JavaScript. And the JavaScript inserts additional elements onto the page. But the PHP DOM will work on the initial HTML and be unable to run the JavaScript since PHP isn't a web browser that is capable of running such JavaScript. As far as options you can try, you might try out selenium or https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin Y said in his comment, you are searching for something that isn't there... yet.

> Visit view-source:https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-7475119/ and search for `<p>`

The page hasn't loaded the extra elements onto it yet like the `<p>` tag you are looking for. This is likely because the page is loading them in after-the-fact using JavaScript so you will need to find a way to get the html after the page has loaded its contents that are added in later.